# How can I get a stable internet connection in Antigua and Barbuda year round?

Tags: digital-nomads

I am looking to apply for the year round 2 year digital nomad visa in Antigua and Barbuda  but have heard conflicting info about internet stability. I work remotely and must have stable connection. Cost is not a factor since I must have this connection. Any suggestions for satellite connections or Internet connections please? Thank you.

Comment: There is none - end of story.

Comment: "must have stable connection" if that's literally true, it won't work.

Comment: Meg, note that it's totally impossible to go live two years somewhere without first "scouting ahead".  You might HATE IT.  (Just one completely random point, you might hate living on only frozen food, which is all that's available on small caribbean islands.) **Grab an airbnb** for a week and go stay there and see what you think.

Comment: @Fattie - I have to assume that you meant something other than what you actually wrote, like "there may be less non-frozen food than you are used to," and not the easily contradicted statement that there is nothing but frozen food in Antigua and Barbuda, which is easily contradicted by a look at some of the [grocery stores](http://www.epicureanantigua.com/gallery.php), for instance, not to mention the personal experience of those of us who have been to those small Caribbean islands. But I still cannot figure out why you would not just write what you actually meant.

Comment: hi @Obie2.0 !  it's hyperbole or idiom - like saying "pizza?! you can't get pizza in new york!"  You know, I have never lived on either Antigua or Barbuda (we lived on a neighboring island).  I think the point is that on "small caribbean islands" (to quote myself) you might find the lifestyle, when you actually live on one as OP plans, surprisingly different from what you're used to. (And from what you "see in movies".)  No digital nomad or P.T. goes somewhere for 1+ years, without, first having a scouting-ahead trip.  (also, i don't specifically remember that grocery, but it looks great!)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Lots to consider- just looking for creative solutions/ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can't realistically make plans to go nomad-stay somewhere for two years, without, first going to stay there for a week (or two) of "scouting ahead".

You just have to accept this as a couple thousand bucks cost for (a) airfare (b) a holiday rental for a week.

Regarding **internet on the small caribbean islands**, the general answer is it is **bad and spotty**.

(For example whenever we have a remote colleague who is hanging out in a Small Caribbean Island, their internet is bad and spotty no matter how much money they throw at the problem.)

You'd need to find someone literally resident in Antigua ATM for an up to the minute report. (I guess it's unlikely you'd choose Barbuda.)